# Make IntelliJ 13 run web application from tomcat directory

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm having issues with running my application through intellij. I would like intellij to not run my application from its own folder (C:\Users[name].IntelliJIdea13...) but instead place my war file or exploded war into my tomcat /webapps folder and run form there. What is happening is i'm having issues accessing resources as my servletcontext points to my tomcat instance by the exploded war is not there, its in Ideas folder structure.

Currently I set CATALINA_BASE in my launch options which allows me to pull the correct keystore to run but that is living outside of the war.

I have tried changing where my artifact outputs too but what ends up happening is I get weird webclassloader errors due to library collision.

Comment: If you have trouble accessing resources, that's because you're not doing it correctly, not because IntelliJ doesn't deploy from Tomcat's directory. Don't assume the war is exploded. Don't use file IO. Use ServletContext.getResourceAsStream() or ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() (depending on where the resource is located).

Comment: There is a reason why I need to do it this way that is insignificant to you. I just want the answer to my question